# Accessing the position of simple shapes

Tags: bonsaijs

I have a `Rect` assigned to a variable myrect:

```
var myrect = new Rect (250,0,20,200);
```

I thought that writing:

```
console.log(myrect.x);
```

would output 250 but, it says "*undefined*".

I would like to know how I can redraw this rectangle by performing
arithmetic on its x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to access the x and y properties is through the `attr()` method.

```
console.log(myrect.attr('x'));
```

See it in the [documentation](http://docs.bonsaijs.org/DisplayObject.html#attr). But I have to admit, the documentation isn't that beginner-friendly yet.